# Codeigniter trouble passing array to view

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, controller

I am trying to pass an array and use it in my view from my controller but instead i am getting some errors...

In my **Controller:**

```
$data = array(
  'a' => 'b',
  'c' => 'd'
);
$this->load->view('home/index', $data);
```

In my **View:**

```
print_r($data);
```

throws errors and doesnt allow me to print it, since i am trying to then pass the array to another view for my app.

**Error**:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: data

Filename: home/index.php

Line Number: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Codeigniter will create variables named with the keys of every item in your data array.

If you want them all in one data array accessible in your view, try that:

```
$data = array(
  'data' => array(
       'a' => 'b',
       'c' => 'd'
  ) 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the view, try accessing as $a and $c rather than $data

Answer (score 0):

$data is just a variable and has nothing to do with the names of variables accessible by the view.

you won't use $data, will use $a and $c because they are the keys of your array values.

Take a look at Codeigniter documentation.